# Ui-Grid: get cellTemplate via promise type error?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I set the gridOptions.columnDefs[col].cellTemplates value as a promise:

```
cellTemplate: $http.get('/templates/customTempTest.html')
```

The TEMPLATE is found returning a status 200 ok. But I get the following error:

[image]

from the following block of code in ui-grid.js file:

[image]

This only happens via promise. If I do the following the template loads fine:

```
cellTemplate:'/templates/customTempTest.html'
```

Comment: Why do you call jQuery `$.get` ?

Comment: @MaximShoustin Iwas just following the following example: http://brianhann.com/6-ways-to-take-control-of-how-your-ui-grid-data-is-displayed/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[$.get](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) is jQuery. Not sure why that was shown in the example. Best not blending the two if necessary. But, to the point -

If you need to do this, and just specifying the path won't work (I've no clue why), then this will work:

```
{
    name: 'email',
    cellTemplate: $http.get('emailTemplate.html')
                   .then(function(r){ return r.data }) }
}
```

I forked a plunk from the [demo](http://brianhann.com/6-ways-to-take-control-of-how-your-ui-grid-data-is-displayed/) that you posted in the comments, and modified it. I also have a simple console output after the $http resolves just for clarity on when things happen.

And here is working plunk:
https://plnkr.co/edit/0WTpaYMc4zejIpeaagkW?p=preview